# Journey Builder reporting

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey that I just started and it is reporting ~600 contacts accepted into journey, but there are no 'sends' being reported (but opens and clicks are being reported).

I don't understand why this would be the case.

Attached is an image displaying the issue:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just lagging in reporting...Looks like it takes more than 20 minutes for reporting to catch up.

Comment: I often find that the open and click data gets updated before the send data does on these journey builder report popups. Like you said usually takes 20 minutes or so to catch up for me too.